# Extra space between fixed and liquid elements in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fixed, liquid-layout

I'm setting up a very simple fixed-liquid layout. The header is set to 100%, the sidebar is set at a fixed width and floated to the left, and the width of the content area is not defined (so that it fills the remaining space).

It works well in every browser except IE, where approximately 3 pixels of white space is added between the sidebar and the content area.

I can't reproduce the problem in JSFiddle (even when I copy and paste my exact code), so I've attached images instead. The first image was rendered in Chrome and the second was rendered in IE9.

[image: Chrome]
[image: IE9]

**CSS** (styles.css)

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #F00;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #0F0;
}

#content {
    height: 1000px;
    background: #00F;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: which version of IE are you running it in?

Comment: Version: 9.0.8112.16421; Update Versions: 9.0.7 (not sure what that means)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding a doctype declaration?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="sidebar"></div>
      <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: That fixed it! That's so weird. I've never understood the doctype declaration. I thought the opening <html> tag was sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, if doctype is omitted IE reverts back to quirksmode for backwards compatability, but declaring one should make it behave as expected. Glad it worked!